# Include image in a project

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, grid, rectangles

I want to include an image in my project from behind-code, in order to permit me to set the image as fill of my rectangle!
I'm inserting an image in this way:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="2" Margin="4,4,4,4" Style="{DynamicResource rectangle_style}" >
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

For create this background image I must include the image file in a project with right click on file and set "include in a project".
Can you help me to include the image from behind-code in run time, because I will have necessity to set image from most file in a folder!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do "Include in Project" or "Add existing item" and under Properties, set "Copy Local" to Always.

Note in this case, you need to get the application folder path

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\[YourPath]\[YourProject]\someImg.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Or bind to a method that provides the current application path for you. (Do a search for this as there are many such questions answered on SO).

This means when you deploy the app, you have to deploy the image with it (it'll end up in the bin folder with whatever path structure you give it).

Another way is to do the same, and set `Build Action` to `Resource` - this will make your application compile with the image inside the DLL. Downside is the DLL will be larger, but you won't have to remember to copy the file when you deploy.

Access the `resource` by name (no front slash)

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="someImg.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Hope it helps!